# Passing html data to a form inside bootstrap modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I have a simple script that collects data from a link and passes it to a form inside of bootstrap modal :

**from link**

```
 <a id="editDetails" title="Edit Details"  href='#myModal2' data-id='<?=$company['id'];?>' class='btn btn-default btn-sm open-EditCompanyDialog'>
```

**to modal**

```
<input id="companyid" name="companyid" type="hidden" class="formBlock btn btn-success"  value=""/>
```

**script**

```
<script>
$(document).on("click", ".open-EditCompanyDialog", function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var _self = $(this);

    var compid = _self.data('id');
    $("#companyid").val(compid);


    $(_self.attr('href')).modal('show');
});
</script>
```

This works fine at getting the id. But what If I want to pass all the other information? Is there a way to do this using html5 data attribute?

**Markup**

```
 <?php while($company=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
  <tr>
      <td data-name="<?=$company['title'];?>" data-th="Name"><?=$company['title'];?></td>
    <td   data-description="<?=$company['description'];?>" data-th="Description"><?=$company['description'];?></td>
    <td  data-type="<?=$company['type'];?>" data-th="Type"><?=$company['type'];?></td>
    <td data-address="<?=$company['address'];?>" data-th="Address"><?=$company['address'];?></td>
    <td data-country="<?=$company['country'];?>" data-th="Country"><?=$company['country'];?></td>
    <td data-timezone="<?=$company['timezone'];?>" data-th="Time Zone"><?=$company['timezone'];?></td>
    <td data-th="ID" sorttable_customkey="2">
       <a id="editDetails" title="Edit Details"  href='#myModal2' data-id='<?=$company['id'];?>' class='btn btn-default btn-sm open-EditCompanyDialog'>
                <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php };?>
```

**EDIT**

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-EditCompanyDialog", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _self = $(this);

    var _parent=$(_self.closest('tr')); //get its parent with closest
    var compid = _self.data('id');
    var compTitle=_parent.find("td[data-th='title']").attr('data-name');
    var compDesc=_parent.find("td[data-th='description']").attr('data-description');
    var compType=_parent.find("td[data-th='type']").attr('data-type');
    var compAdd=_parent.find("td[data-th='address']").attr('data-address');
    var compZone=_parent.find("td[data-th='timezone']").attr('data-timezone');
    var compCountry=_parent.find("td[data-th='country']").attr('data-country');

    $("#companyid").val(compid);
    $("#compname").val(compTitle);
    $("#description").val(compDesc);
    $("#type").val(compType);
    $("#address").val(compAdd);
    $("#timezone").val(compZone);
    $("#country").val(compCountry);
    $(_self.attr('href')).modal('show');
});
```

**EDIT FULL MODAL WITH FORM INSIDE**

```
<form id="editCompany" method="POST" action="core/query.php">
     <input id='compname'name='title' value='' type='text' placeholder="Name...">
     <input id="companyid" name="companyid" type="hidden"value=""/>

     <select name='type'>
     <option> Type...</option>
     <option id='type' value="" selected></option>
     </select>

     <select name='description'>
     <option  value="">Description...</option>
     <option id='description' value="" selected></option>
     </select> 

     <input id='address' name='address' value='' type='text' placeholder="Address">

     <select name="country" value='' type='text' placeholder="Country">
     <option value="">Country...</option>
     <option  id='country' value="" selected></option>
     </select>

     <select name="timezone">
     <option value=''>Timezone...</option>
     <option  id='timezone' value="" selected></option>
     </select>

     <input name="editCompany" id="submit" type="submit" value="Modify Data"/>

</form>
```

Comment: Like `address`, `title` and all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a solution that works on `inputs` and `divs`. It does not work with `option` tag. But I have decided to run with this solution and work around the issue. Take note everything is on the same page. Gather all data on the button then use jQuery to pass data to your modal as follow:

```
 <?php while($company=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){ ?>
  <tr>
      <td  data-th="Name"><?=$company['title'];?></td>
    <td    data-th="Description"><?=$company['description'];?></td>
    <td  data-th="Type"><?=$company['type'];?></td>
    <td  data-th="Address"><?=$company['address'];?></td>
    <td  data-th="Country"><?=$company['country'];?></td>
    <td  data-th="Timezone"><?=$company['timezone'];?></td>
    <td data-th="ID" sorttable_customkey="2">

<button type='button' class='btn btn-default btn-sm open-EditCompanyDialog' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal2'  data-name="<?=$company['title'];?>" data-description="<?=$company['description'];?>" data-type="<?=$company['type'];?>" data-address="<?=$company['address'];?>" data-country="<?=$company['country'];?>" data-timezone="<?=$company['timezone'];?>" >
    <i class="fa fa-pencil-square-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <?php };?>
```

**Then inside your modal...**

```
    <form id="editCompany" method="POST" action="query.php">
    <!-- Modal -->
    <div id="myModal2" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Edit Company Details</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
         <input id="companyid" name="companyid" type="hidden" class="formBlock btn btn-success"  value=""/>
         <input id='compname' class='form-control formBlock' name='title' value='' type='text' placeholder="Name...">
        <input id='type' class='form-control formBlock' name='type' value='' type='text'>
    <input id='description' class='form-control formBlock' name='description' value='' type='text'>
    <input id='country' class='form-control formBlock' name='country' value='' type='text'>
    <input id='timezone' class='form-control formBlock' name='timezone' value='' type='text'>
        <input id='address' class='form-control formBlock' name='address' value='' type='text'>

    <div class="modal-footer">
          <div class='col-md-12'>

        <input name="editCompany" id="submit" type="submit" class="formBlock btn btn-success"  value="Modify Data"/>
          </div></div>
    </div></div>
</form>
```

**script**

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myModal2').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) { // id of the modal with event
      var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
      var id = button.data('id') // Extract info from data-* attributes
      var name = button.data('name')
                             var description = button.data('description')
                             var type= button.data('type')
                              var address = button.data('address')
                              var country = button.data('country')
                              var timezone = button.data('timezone')
      // Update the modal's content.
      var modal = $(this)
      modal.find('#companyid').val(id)
                            modal.find('#compname').val(name)
                            modal.find('#description').val(description)
                            modal.find('#type').val(type)
                            modal.find('#address').val(address)
                            modal.find('#country').val(country)
                            modal.find('#timezone').val(timezone)

    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access other informations as below:

```
var com_type = _self.parent().parent().find('[data-type]').html()
var com_name = _self.parent().parent().find('[data-name]').html()
....
```

I hope this will help you!

Comment: I might give the answer to you. It works for inputs I was capable to show value but it does not show in <option> tags.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is, get the parent `tr` of particular edit button with **[`.closest`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)** and then fetch each data from `td` one by one based on their `data-th` attribute.

Consider below example:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-EditCompanyDialog", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _self = $(this);
    var _parent=$(_self.closest('tr')); //get its parent with closest
    var compid = _self.data('id');
    var compTitle=_parent.find("td[data-th='title']").attr('data-name');
    var compDesc=_parent.find("td[data-th='description']").attr('data-name');
    var compType=_parent.find("td[data-th='type']").attr('data-name');
    var compAdd=_parent.find("td[data-th='address']").attr('data-name');

    //Other 2 options country and timezone too..

    $("#companyid").val(compid);
    $(_self.attr('href')).modal('show');
});
```

> But this is not the right way to do it because, you are getting
>   everything from client side and this can be changed at any point of
>   time by `client`. So what I would suggest is, since you have `id`
>   obtained from `data-id` attribute, perform an `ajax` call to server/db
>   and get the necessary details as `json` response from server, before
>   poping up the `modal`.

A typical example would be:

```
$(document).on("click", ".open-EditCompanyDialog", function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var _self = $(this);
    var compid = _self.data('id');
    $.get('someurl/method?id='+compid,function(response){
         //parse response and get the details, set the values and then show the modal
         $("#companyid").val(compid);
         $(_self.attr('href')).modal('show');
    });
});
```

> You can also make use of various **[`events available in bootstrap modal`](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)** like before showing `modal`, after showing `modal` etc., and make your `get` call to server.

Comment: I tried your first method just to try and the data does not get appended to the `<option></option>` on the form inside the modal. Example `<option id='type' value="" selected></option>` returns no value inside.

Comment: Also, could you add code within `modal`, the `form` which you are talking about..

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code? I'm trying to make it work because it seems to be the best solution so far.

Comment: You should be having some default values in your select field, including the one the edited item has.. So when you say `$("#type").val(compType);` it will by default select the appropriate option when you edit.. But I don't see any initial values there..